# tikz: fancy polyhedron in three dimensional space

Tags: tikz-pgf

For my master's thesis I want to draw a convex polyhedron in a three dimensional space. I think I already have a good solution but I am not completely satisfied yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
        \draw[->, thick]
            (0.5,0.5) -- (1.5,0.5) node[below] {$v_1$};
        \draw[->, thick]
            (0.5,0.5) -- (0.5,1.5) node[left] {$v_2$};
        \draw[->, thick]
            (0.5,0.5) -- (0,0) node[above left] {$v_3$};
        \draw[densely dashed]
            (1.05, 1.24) -- (0.5,0.5);
        \draw[densely dashed]
            (1.315, 1.125) -- (0.5,0.5);    
        \draw[thick, fill=red]
            (0.5,0.5) -- (0.8,1.2) -- (0.9,1.00) -- (0.5,0.5) -- (1.3,1) --(0.9,1.00);
        \draw[thick, fill opacity=0.3, fill=red]
            (1.3,1) -- (1.315,1.125) -- (1.05,1.24) -- (0.80,1.20) -- (0.9,1.00) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the attached figure, two edges are not "smooth". It seems that the lines that form the edge "overlap" somehow.

[image: Polyhedron]

Anyone have an idea how to avoid this effect?

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! "line join=bevel" works perfectly for me.

Comment: @percusse -- deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Can you explain this in more detail?

Comment: sorry, i'm not a skilled `tikz` user, so the reasoning is beyond me.  i suggested that @percusse post an answer since you confirmed that what he suggested fixed the problem, and we really don't like to leave questions unanswered.  perhaps he can give a more complete explanation as well.  (another reason why it deserves an answer is that you provided both your code in a compilable example, and the image of the output.  well done!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Answer added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During the drawing, if the path is making a corner then it is visually more pleasing if the corner is drawn as if forming a miter joint. But there is a limit to this effect. If we look at the following simple example

```
\tikz\foreach\x in {0,5,...,75,76,77,...,90}{\draw[opacity=\x/100](0,0)--+(-\x:1)--+(\x:1);}
```

we get

[image]

Here, as you can see, as the angle gets more acute the miter effect is more pronounced. But because after some point it just becomes a numerical artifact and starts to look strange, there is an inherent limit calculated as the path is drawn. You can control this via the `miter limit` key. That's what happens around when the angle gets 78 degrees or so, the joint is switched to `bevel`

Or you can completely turn it off by using a different line joining via using the other options of this key.

```
line join=<miter|bevel|round>
```

Comment: I think I have pretty much always used `join=round` and it seems to be a better choice in this case as well.

Comment: Now i tried `join=round`. The result is really better in comparisson to `join=bevel` but the difference is just visible if you zoom in 2500 %. But better is better... ;)